# Creating a table in Crystal Reports Basic (one built in vs2008)?

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to create a table with this crystal reports, because I need to layout or format my data into a table(not cross tab), is there a way to do this cause I think my tool box is only limited to lines and boxes and basic shapes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few things you can do to make it look like a table:

- **Create Each row** in your report represents a row in the table.
- **Put a border/box around the table** use the 'Insert Box' from the toolbar and simple start drawing the box in the header of the (or group header) and finish in the footer (or group footer) and when you preview the report you'll see a box around the whole table [report]
- **Column grid lines** can easily be done by linking the top and bottom of your box. they will then expand out in preview mode.

**Top Tip:** Zooming right in, to say 300%, makes getting the joins much easier, and investigate snap-to-grid you may want to simple disable it it may actually make life easier,(when ultimate precision is required)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display the data as a table, you can get creative with details, groups, subsections, and formulae.  For example, the formula `sum({A},{B})` adds all the values of {A} for each group {B} (best used in a group footer).  If you have any specific questions, I can try to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but Crystal reports can not create tables.  It can execute a stored procedure that creates tables, but that's really the procedure creating the tables.

Comment: I don't want to down-vote, but it's clear to me that the question wasn't referring to CREATE TABLE. Strange that your answer has been accepted!

Comment: @Dog Ears, you could well be right, but if so, I have no idea what the quesiton is.  Of course, you can make the data -look like- a table I suppose.

Comment: Ok Can you suggest how can i create a table. What i mean by table is that it shows the data in columns and rows with the borders etc... any ideas?? since i believe there is no table control, only plain boxes lines etc

Comment: All you have to do is use the formatting to put lines on all sides of the field.  Of course it helps to put the fields next to each other so that there are no spaces between them.  The natural flow of the data will be down the page, so a grid will appear.  i hope I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Thnaks for the suggestions guys