# How to make a show/hide table columns (grid) when corresponding columns are shown or hidden in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am creating dynamic columns in Crystal report. Columns are showing and hiding successfully but i am  unable to show/hide the corresponding table grid lines. I drew lines to make a table grid but problem is that lines are not hiding when columns are hidden.

The design (layout) of my report is as below

```
Name    Age  Gender    Adress   description
  abc   20    m        ab
  xyz   30    f         
  s     40    m
```

1)I created a table grid through lines but problem is when one or two columns are hidden, blank lines are show in grid which means lines are not hiding and looks ugly.

2)I created a table using the text objects borders setting but the problem here is when a column is full empty or partially empty or some cell on a row is empty for eg. description then text object border will not show in detail section.

Can someone please guide with this.

Answer (score 0):

After a major edit of your question, please have a look at my suggestion for an answer. 
CR does not support tables. Period. The best option you have here is to follow your first method (using lines) and then use Suppression formula same as you are using to make your columns dynamic. So when the column data is hidden the respective lines are hidden too. Thats your best shot, because CR does not have a grid control.

Few tips taken from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316249/creating-a-table-in-crystal-reports-basicone-built-in-vs2008) on SO that might give you more idea on how to design a table.

- Create Each row in your report represents a row in the table.
- Put a border/box around the table use the 'Insert Box' from the
  toolbar and simple start drawing the box in the header of the (or
  group header) and finish in the footer (or group footer) and when you
  preview the report you'll see a box around the whole table [report]
- Column grid lines can easily be done by linking the top and bottom of
  your box. they will then expand out in preview mode.
- Top Tip: Zooming right in, to say 300%, makes getting the joins much
  easier, and investigate snap-to-grid you may want to simple disable
  it it may actually make life easier,(when ultimate precision is
  required)